# If Else Statement not working ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, radio-button

Index.aspx

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rbt1" runat="server" Text="By Customer" GroupName="summary" OnCheckedChanged="enabled_CheckedChanged" Checked="True"/>
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rbt4" runat="server" Text="With Target" OnCheckedChanged="enabled_CheckedChanged" GroupName="summary"/>
```

Index.aspx.cs

```
public void enabled_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (rbt4.Checked == true)
      {
           rbt1.Checked = true;
      }
      else
      {
           rbt1.Checked = false;
      }
}
```

The purpose of the code is when rbt1 is checked, rbt4 will be checked. User can also check rbt4 after checking rbt1. However, if rbt4 is checked, rbt1 will be checked automatically. The code above was used but it doesn't seem to be working. Did I miss out something or is there error in my coding? Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note : `rbt1.Checked = rbt4.Checked` with no if statements can replace your code. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not clear on your requirements as your explanation seems to be inconsistent. Which checkbox is bound to the other? Will rbt1 be the bound one or will it be rbt4. Your code suggests that rbt1 will be bound to rbt4, but your explanation suggests otherwise in certain parts.

Comment: Moreover, could you please tell us exactly what is not working? Does it not work when the page loads or does it not work after the user (you) manually checks a checkbox?

Comment: "User can also check rbt 4 after checking rbt 1."
You have both `rtb4` and `rtb1` hooked to the same event : `enabled_CheckedChanged`.
So when `rtb4` is not checked it will be impossible to set `rtb1` to true

Comment: @CanIbanoglu rbt1 will be bounded to rbt4

Answer (score 1):

You are using radio button and want to select multiple but radio button are mutually exclusive with same `GroupName`. You can not select more then one RadioButton with same group. You probably need to use the [CheckBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s78d0k1(v=vs.71).aspx) for selecting multiple, or Giving different GroupName to exceptional cases may sort out the problem or you may need combination of checkboxes with radiobuttons or nested html-checkboxes.

> Use the GroupName property to specify a grouping of radio buttons to
>   create a mutually exclusive set of controls. You can use the GroupName
>   property when only one selection is possible from a list of available
>   options. When this property is set, only one RadioButton in the
>   specified group can be selected at a time, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want to make some relation in checkbox like if one is selected then some other should be selected and nothing more then that then you may use client side script to save unnecessary PostBacks and smooth user experience.

Comment: There are actually many radio buttons for users to select. I used the GroupName property so that there won't be multiple selection. However, rbt4 is sort of an extension of rbt1. So would using checkbox be able to meet my requirements?

Comment: Giving different GroupName to exception may sort out the problem.

Comment: could you please explain the meaning of giving different GroupName to exception? I do not understand what it means to exception

Comment: Those radio button that could be selected at the same time should have different GroupName like rbt4 and rbt1 should have different group name to select both at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Both radio buttons have the same `GroupName`. Only one of them can be checked at a time. Change `GroupName` property of radio buttons to fix the error. refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx) for clarity. Also add `AutoPostBack="true" property to radio button code.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this coding Note: AutoPostBack="true". Remove the Same group name for Both Radio Button.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />

protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton2.Checked = true;
        }
```

Comment: would it be necessary for autopostback = "true"? There are still other parts of the form for users to select their options.

Comment: otherwise it's not working. You need to add this Property.

Answer (score 0):

Please add : `AutoPostBack="true"` in your html code

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbt1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="By Customer"GroupName="summary" OnCheckedChanged="enabled_CheckedChanged" Checked="True" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rbt4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="With Target" OnCheckedChanged="enabled_CheckedChanged" GroupName="summary" />
```